# How to match a string with the format: “20959WC-01” in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have to restrict a user to input a value which match the given format: "20959WC-01". How to do this in jQuery?

Comment: What does this question have to do with *"...class in the Apple developer library (Mac OS X, iOS) [that] is used to represent and apply regular expressions to Unicode strings..."*?

Comment: jQuery doesn't help you here. Read up on [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), give it a go, maybe play around on http://regex101.com/#javascript, and if you run into a *specific* problem, post what you've tried and people will be happy to help.

Comment: Use regex something like `[0-9]{5}[a-zA-Z]{2}\-\[0-9]{2}`

Comment: /^[0-9]{5}[a-zA-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}/ it is working for me, but i am unable to restrict last two integers, means if a user enters more than 2 integers at last, then it still submits the value, which should not, can anyone solve this out?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I went ahead and fixed the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have got the solution:
here it is:

```
if(!case_val.match(/^[0-9]{5}[a-zA-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/)) {
    /* */
}
```

it is working fine for me, thanks to stack-overflow :)